# Execute stored procedure if multiple records exists within 1 minute from same location (IP)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Whenever a record is inserted into my database a trigger is fired that will execute a stored procedure to send an email alert if a condition is met on the database. I need the procedure to execute if multiple records exists in the db within a certain period of time (if 5 records exists within 1 minute from same IP and login type)

```
IF (SELECT IP, COUNT(*) AS Counted
    FROM LOGS  
     AND Logs.TYPE = 'Visitor' 
    HAVING Counted >= 5
       AND IP > 1 
      AND ACCESSEDTIME > DATEADD(minute, -1, GetDate())) > 0
BEGIN
    -- my stored procedure
END
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and stored procedures are highly vendor specific. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using

Comment: Side note: [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) is going to give you a **lot** of false positives....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it wuold be something like this but in your example it is not so clear...

```
IF exists (Select ip, count(*) as counted from logs
where logs.type='Visitor' and
ACCESSEDTIME > DATEADD(minute, -1, GetDate())
Group by ip having count (*) >= 5)
```

Then you can execute this every minute and test, but it is not so good.
In alternative you can test using the minute as term of `Group by` clause, extracting it from accessdtime (how it depends by your product).

Comment: This works with a slight modification. I needed to add `IF exists (SELECT...` to the beginning and then the stored procedure would execute after the number of IP entries in the DB reaches or exceeds 5. There is no reason to execute this every minute as I only want the stored proc to execute when the condition is met and a trigger is set up to fire this with each row inserted into the DB. Basically, if a user enters an incorrect username/password 5 times in my application - within a minute, I'll get an email notification.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below query. Details were not very clear so you might have to make some adjustments.

```
IF exists (SELECT IP,
COUNT(ip) AS Counted    
FROM LOGS     
where  Logs.TYPE = 'Visitor'   
group by ip
HAVING COUNT(ip) >= 5      
AND IP > 1 AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, accessedtime, 
getdate())) =1
BEGIN
-- my stored procedure
END
```